# Can data augmentation techniques be misleading?

Tags: class-imbalance, data-augmentation

In an attempt to handle imbalance in data, especially in the case of extremely imbalanced data, can the various data augmentation techniques create some bias?

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. You should probably make your question more specific, but in short: yes, of course.

Comment: Thank you for replying. What I'm seeking help to understand is that should the focus be on building a model with low variance and bias or try and handle this bias post the data augmentation stage prior to modeling and what methods could be used.

Comment: I think this question of data augmentation is very dependent on the kind of task and data. For example with text data it's very rare to see any data augmentation technique actually improving performance in any way, as far as I know. But it's quite standard with image processing tasks apparently. In general it's not sure that the bias caused by data augmentation can be handled, because it changes the data distribution and that can affect performance.

Comment: From my recent experience I have noticed that the best way to validate if the data augmentation is misleading is to test your model on new/unseen data and compare the performance metrics. If you get a poor performing model some additional training data or a different approach should be tried.